# I want the logo in center

Tags: css, wordpress

There is a website which was made by me on WordPress . Website link is 
[loophole.ml/admin](http://loophole.ml/admin), I need a small help when you visit the website. It logo is not in the position I want the logo in the position means in the centre.

Comment: you have to add do some css stuff

Answer (score 0):

Add "margin-top" to the .site-branding class in the style.css of your theme:

```
.site-branding {
float: left;
padding: 0 0 0;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```